# How do I get the ID of a rows which have MAX and MIN values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make the queries my website uses more efficient.

Being a bit vague about SQL, I've not really learnt how to use nested queries, but I have just managed to get something that is pretty near what I want.

I sell guitars, I have a big database with all the products with different finish options listed individually. Items have unique IDs in the dB but are grouped by their title, for example, a Gibson Les Paul Standard is listed in my dB 7 times with 7 different finish options. Not all the finish options will necessarily have the same price, and not all finish options will necessarily be in stock.

In the search results page of my website I want to be able to show:

1) Just one record per product, ie 1 record for Gibson LP Std, which can then be sub-linked to the different finishes.

2) The actual product displayed must *either* be the cheapest finish option, OR, the cheapest in stock.

This is currently working on my website, but it's using N+1 queries and seems to be running dreadfully slowly, but for an example of what I mean, click here: http://www.hartnollguitars.co.uk/search.asp?subcat=Gibson-Les-Pauls (if the bloody thing works)

Part one is fine, I can just group the title in SQL, it's getting part 2 out that's the problem.

Using the following SQL query I can get the lowest price and the highest price and I have counted how many variants there are, I also have the max and min stock levels.

```
results.Open "SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT *, count(id) as Variants, MAX(price) as highestPrice, MIN(price) as
lowestPrice, MAX(shopstock) as highestStock, MIN(shopstock) as lowestStock FROM 
products WHERE item LIKE '%"& replace([searchterm]," ","%") &"%' GROUP BY item) 
AS UnknownVar LIMIT 40", conn, 3, &H0001
```

What I need to be able to do is get the ID value for the rows representing the max and min stock and price values.

I basically need to be able to run if/or logic on it and I am not sure if this is possible.

So, I need to be able to say

```
if Item_With_Cheapest_Price is in stock, display this as the thumbnail & link
else 
display first item in price sorted list where stock >=1
```

I also need a fall back, if none of the finishes are in stock, display the cheapest one.

The database is MySQL using ODBC connections, I am currently scripting in Classic ASP but aim to upgrade to .NET, once I've worked out how!!! :-)

Comment: to have an idea, how many records there are in the item table?

Comment: stivlo; There are several thousand products in total, but the grouped value of item (ie Gibson Les Paul Standard) should have no more than about 20 finish options.

Comment: I was suspecting that. Unrelated to your question, but a reason for the slowness is this part of the query WHERE item LIKE '%"& replace([searchterm]," ","%" -- since the % sign is in front of the term indexes can't be used and MySQL will have to check **every single row**. Take a look at [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Thanks Stivlo, I've had a look at that, but now I can't get sensible results with multi-word queries, for example, a search for Gibson LEs Paul just generates ALL Gibson entries. Using
WHERE MATCH (item) AGAINST ('"&[searchterm]&"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Comment: Where is the requirement to get the max price coming from?

Comment: oh nvm, i see on your site you say how many are in stock

Comment: kralco626, I actually don't necessarily need the max price, but I do need to be able to display the lowest price item IF it is in stock, so need to get it's ID (and pic), but if it's not in stock I need to cycle up to the next one that is in stock. I also need to be able to list ALL options in the grouping to display the mini-menu of options.

Comment: When I get some time I'll take a deeper look, but what you should consider is solving this problem using a two part solution. Possibly changing both how the query works, and changing how your application works. If you can delay some of the "work" out of the initial load that could be beneficial. Did you write the site? Do you know how to use javascript, Jquery and AJax? Using those strategies could help you offload some of the processing from the initial load.

Comment: Also the structure of your table(s) would be helpful in trying to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks kralco626. I did write the site, kinda going to redo it though as in the development of it I have learnt a LOT of better ways to do things! Yes, I do know some javascript and jQuery stuff, but I want to ensure the whole thing will function without javascript, so don't want it to rely on it. I am currently messing with GROUP_CONCAT which looks like it *might* return arrays I can use, I'm currently getting very odd characters though!

Comment: Although making the site not work without java script is very nice of you, not many people don't have javascript these days. And the ones that don't proly wont be buying your guitars... I don't have any facts to back this up... but... Anyways... there is still some stuff you could do. Like do you really need to load the number in stock for the couple of people that don't have javascript? Stuff like that.

Comment: And even without javascript, you could still execute more than one query to get the information you need... If you could post the table structure that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think for the order by part you should use something like

```
order by case
    when stock > 0 then 0
    when stock < 0 then 1
    end ascending,
    price ascending
```

I didn't check the syntax but that's the idea. You can google case in order by for more info.

As for the rest of you requirements I would need the table structure to better understand...

Comment: Ah, that could help simplify things. I'll check it out tomorrow, gotta run now. Have been getting pretty good results with GROUP_CONCAT which seems to generate an array of items within the group. This is useful, if order by case can allow me to get these arrays in the right order it'd save sorting the array and could give me exactly what I need... Can't get back to this now til next week though! :-(

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the concept of dense_rank? If not I could explain it to you. Your purpose could be solved by following queries. Have a look at this.

```
SELECT id,
MIN(stock) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY stock,price) "Lowest"
,MAX(stock) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY stock,price) "Highest"
FROM products
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Hi, that looks interesting, can you elaborate on what it actually does?

Comment: hi can u give ur requirement in nut shell ..i.e.wat do you want then i would b able to giv u xact query

Comment: try this http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm

Comment: that looks interesting. Irritatingly, my attention has been drawn off this issue now on to other things, but I will come back to this for certain. Thanks for all the help :)